# Gitlab public repo clone fails with "401 Unauthorized"

Tags: clone, public, repository, gitlab

I'm hoping someone can help me diagnose this issue.  I'm running Gitlab 5.2 on a default Ubuntu 12.04 install with the latest ruby and git.  It's mostly vanilla with the exception of some LDAP mapping modifications (username, display name).

I'm running into an error with Gitlab that I'm having trouble diagnosing.  Whenever I attempt to clone a 'public' repo, instead of the expected (and working on CentOS with the same LDAP mapping modifications):

```
Started GET "/dd/lol.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-17 10:21:55 -0400
Started POST "/dd/lol.git/git-upload-pack" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-17 10:21:55 -0400
```

I get (on Ubuntu):

```
Started GET "/dd/lol.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-17 10:26:13 -0400
Started GET "/dd/lol.git/HEAD" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-17 10:26:13 -0400
Started GET "/dd/lol.git/HEAD" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-17 10:26:15 -0400
Started GET "/dd/lol.git/HEAD" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-17 10:26:15 -0400
Started GET "/dd/lol.git/objects/8c/4e72acdc72843492f55d5918f53dd12e5f1e43" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-17 10:26:15 -0400
Started GET "/dd/lol.git/objects/info/packs" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-17 10:26:15 -0400
```

On the client side I get consistent "401 Unauthorized" messages, then I'm prompted for a password.  It doesn't seem to be related to Apache or Nginx proxying.

Client-side log:

```
git clone http://127.0.0.1:9292/dd/lol.git
Cloning into 'lol'...
* Couldn't find host 127.0.0.1 in the .netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 9292 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7fc610803000
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7fc610803000) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 9292 (#0)
> GET /dd/lol.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: git/1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37)
Host: 127.0.0.1:9292
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Last-Modified: Mon, 17 Jun 2013 14:33:31 GMT
< Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
< X-Request-Id: 0a9ec65cffb7888fb6fbc136171fa80a
< X-Runtime: 0.079635
< Date: Mon, 17 Jun 2013 14:33:31 GMT
< X-Content-Digest: 198141e92e2cf9bb83d1aa1022fdea885993f02e
< Age: 0
< X-Rack-Cache: stale, invalid, store
< Content-Length: 59
< 
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
* Couldn't find host 127.0.0.1 in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Found bundle for host 127.0.0.1: 0x7fc6104155f0
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host 127.0.0.1
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 9292 (#0)
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7fc610803000
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7fc610803000) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
> GET /dd/lol.git/HEAD HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: git/1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37)
Host: 127.0.0.1:9292
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Pragma: no-cache

* The requested URL returned error: 401 Unauthorized
* Closing connection 0
```

Any suggestions at all are very welcome, I'm not familiar with Gitlab and I'm currently a bit stumped.

- Dmitry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloning with LDAP activated seems to be a recurring problem, especially over https:

- [issue 4288](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4288)
- [issue 3890](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3890)
- [issue 4129](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4129)

A workaround is [proposed here](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commit/20a88f5c43efa3ab0af80d26c90268132e6f7997#commitcomment-3167528), and is related to file  [`lib/gitlab/backend/grack_auth.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/lib/gitlab/backend/grack_auth.rb#L66-L80), but a final fix is still in progress.

Update: from 5.3+ and 6.x, this should have been fixed.

Comment: Thank you for an informative and concise answer.  Very much appreciated.