# gitlab can not clone by http and check is error

Tags: gitlab, ubuntu-12.10

I have installed gitlab and the website is ok, but when i use clone, I always get

```
fatal: Authentication failed.
```

but the username and password is correct, and when I use

> bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production

the answer is

```
Checking GitLab Shell..
rake aborted!
undefined method 'match' for nil:NilClass
/home/git/git/gitlab/lib/gitlab/version_info.rb:8:in `parse`
/home/git/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/check.rake:659:in 'check_gitlab_shell'
```

Did I install gitlab-shell incorrectly? How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have LDAP activated, as in http://stackoverflow.com/q/17150394/6309 ?

Comment: What version of Gitlab and Gitlab shell are you using?